# Applying Conditional Formatting to all computed values in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: formatting, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, how can I use the Conditional Formatting feature to apply a style to all cells which contain a computed value (via formula, as opposed to a directly input value)?

---

- LibreOffice version 4.1.4.2
- Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a two ways:

1. Define a conditional formatting rule, based on "**`Formula is`**" and use the [**`ISFORMULA()`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#ISFORMULA) function:

   > ISFORMULA(A1)

   The cell reference depends on your starting point. If you want to apply the conditional formatting to range `B8:F20`, it would be `ISFORMULA(B8)`; LibreOffice adapts the cell reference for all cells of the selected range automatically.

   [image: Conditional formatting]

   (If you need more control, e.g. to distinguish between text, number, bool or error, you could also use the [**`TYPE`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#TYPE) function.)
2. Alternatively, to simply display computed values and text/number values in different color globally, just activate "**`Value Highlighting`**" from the Calc options. This will display computed values in a different color than text/number values. The setting affects all ods files, and (AFAIK) you can't modify the style how to display values / formula results.

   [image: Options - Value Highlighting]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! The explanation about cell references helped especially.

Comment: Change colors of 2: "These colors can be customized in Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Application Colors."
https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/03080000.html